# Distributing 5 balls in 3 boxes, the harder way.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am having problem in doing this simple combinatorics problem which says that I have $3$ boxes and $5$ balls and I want to distribute the balls in the way it is shown in the figure (the boxes and the balls are not identical)

[image]

(The figure represents one of the situations, we need to permute it also. By that I mean to say that we can permute the boxes also. )

A simple way to do that is $$\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3} \cdot {3! \over 2!} = \color{green}{60} $$
I tried to decipher the question in a harder way so as to get my concepts cleared on permutation.

First I took one of the blocks and permuted it and then put one of the five balls in it and permuted the balls too by writing $$P(3,1) \cdot P(5,1)$$

For the second box we have $$P(2,1) \cdot P(4,1)$$

Coming on to the last box we can write $$P(1,1) \cdot P(3,3)/ 3!$$ (I divided by $3!$ since order doesn't matter for the balls in the third box as we are not arranging but distributing.)

Combining the three terms we get

$$ P(3,1) \cdot P(5,1) \cdot P(2,1) \cdot P(4,1) \cdot P(1,1) \cdot {P(3,3) \over  3!}= \color{red}{120}$$

What's the problem with my approach in solving by the second method?

Comment: Not following your calculation...what does it mean to say that you "took one of the blocks and permuted it"?  What's a block?   At what point do you address the symmetry between boxes I and II?  That's a factor of two right there....

Comment: Actually, I'm not even clear on the question.  You have three boxes...are they distinguishable?  Are the five balls distinguishable?  And the goal is to distribute the five balls so that two boxes have one each and the other has three?  Or is the goal something else?

Comment: You are right. The balls are distinguishable the boxes are not.

Comment: Ok...but then it seems to me that you just need to choose the three balls that are in one box.  Thus I see the answer as $\binom 53$.

Comment: I think according to figure boxes are fix.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh  You mean they are distinguishable?  But the OP says otherwise. Of course, you may well be right.  My sense is that this problem is not well posed.

Comment: Answer in your first method is correct?

Comment: And why you are multiplying with 3!/2! in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where you are wrong.

For first box we have $$P(3,1) \cdot P(5,1)$$

For the second box we have $$P(2,1) \cdot P(4,1)$$

So indirectly you are having 6 ways to choose from 3 boxes when you multiply theses cases. Which is not true as we can pick 3 boxes only in 3 ways.

> Solution -

Divide your answer at last step by 2 to get correct result.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your last step is that the order in which you fill boxes is not relevant. 
Let's say the boxes are box 1, 2, and 3 and balls are 1,2,3,4,5.

Box 1.Ball 1.Box 2.Ball 2. Box 3. Ball3,4,5
Box 2.Ball 2.Box 1.Ball 1. Box 3. Ball3,4,5

There are the exact same outcomes, yet your last statement counts them as two.

Comment: It migh look stupid that I am asking it now, but I think I have not understood the concept properly.  If the boxes are distinguishable,  how can your configurations be same?  Can you please elaborate it.

Comment: @Harsh Your first attempt in your question is the correct and simple attempt. Your second method turns out to give double the correct answer because you are counting all cases twice. In your second attempt, you select one box, put a ball in it, then select another box, put a ball in it and then in the last box, put 3 balls in it. Note that you are to selec t the boxes (combinations), what you have done is taken into account order of selection (permutations).